# Can't install R package "graph3d" from Github

Tags: r, github, install.packages

I tried install "graph3d" R package in this way:

---

```
if(!require(devtools)) install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("kassambara/graph3d", quiet = F )
```

---

But obtain the error with that outcome:

---

> Downloading GitHub repo kassambara/graph3d@master
>
> from URL
>   https://api.github.com/repos/kassambara/graph3d/zipball/master
>
> Installing graph3d "C:/Program Files/R/R-34~1.1/bin/x64/R"
>   --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD  \ INSTALL
>   "C:/Users/Ostap/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpAvMz4w/devtools21806e4276dd/kassambara-graph3d-483d846"
>   \
>     --library="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.1/library" --install-tests
>
> ---
>
> "C:\Program" ­Ґ пў«пҐвбп ў­гваҐ­­Ґ© Ё«Ё ў­Ґи­Ґ© Є®¬ ­¤®©, ЁбЇ®«­пҐ¬®© Їа®Ја ¬¬®© Ё«Ё Ї ЄҐв­л¬ д ©«®¬.
>
> Installation failed: Command failed (1)
>
> ---

What is the reason ? Is anyone can explain how to fix it? I will really appreciate to that person. Thank's also even for attempts & suggestions:)

---

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved by reinstalling R and Rtools in directory with level names without gap (such as "Program Files"). After that for analisis environment perpose I use one-by-one execution of commands:

> find_rtools()

[1] TRUE

> has_devel()

"C:/R-34~1.2/bin/x64/R" --no-site-file --no-environ --no-save --no-restore --quiet CMD SHLIB foo.c

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc  -I"C:/R-34~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG     -I"d:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -shared -s -static-libgcc -o foo.dll tmp.def foo.o -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib/x64 -Ld:/Compiler/gcc-4.9.3/local330/lib -LC:/R-34~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
[1] TRUE

[1] TRUE

**So then installaion graph2d package and anotherones from Github:**

> devtools::install_github("kassambara/graph3d", quiet = FALSE )

**work properly)** Problem solved.